# Vuetify rating component is not rendering

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vuetify.js

I am trying to use Vuetify rating component in my app (https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/ratings#ratings). I have Vuetify 1.5.5 installed, other components like buttons work fine. In this rating, the stars are not being rendered, only the text.

Any ideas about how I can fix this? I didn't find any relevant posts online. If someone can recommend any other stable vue rating component, that would also work.

This is the component where I am using the rating:

```
 <div>
    <span class="headerText">Dataset Product</span>
    <span class="headerDesc">Short description</span>
    <span class="headerDesc">@georgeBush.</span>
    <v-rating v-model="rating"></v-rating>
 </div>
```

My main.js file which has vuetify css import:

```
import Vuetify from 'vuetify'
import 'vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css'
```

I have also attached the screenshot of what was rendered.

[Screenshot of rendered rating component, no stars](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OxRuK.png)

Comment: Did you define `rating` which is the `v-model` in the `data` section of your script?

Comment: Please add your script code or atleast data property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears you may not using Material Icons library.  https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700|Material+Icons

I was able to reproduce the error when I removed it from a Codepen.

Comment: Thank you @excessjudgement. This resolved the issue. Cheers mate!